# Xingcloud script added on EasyPHP

Tags: javascript, easyphp

I was working on my website when looked my source code to see if it was nice after processed by EasyPHP. But there was a script added on my code that was not wrote in files before being processed. The script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://aimg.xingcloud.com/xxxxxxx"></script>
```

xxxxxxx = bd.js?03372d

Made it just to prevent any problem, I dont know if it's malicious. I didnt find ANY link talking about it in Google, so, yea, does anyone have an idea about what it is and how I can remove it? Thanks, hope you understood my speach.

Answer (score 2):

[According to Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/entry.aspx?Name=Trojan:Win32/Wysotot.F#tab=2), this may be a trojan infecting your computer. I suggest you run some virus scanning.